# Pagination meteor publish does not return records

Tags: pagination, publish-subscribe, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I definitely know that something is wrong with this snippet but can't figure out the right way to get it done. I want to paginate the page where students are displayed. If I put it plainly like this `return SchoolStudents.find();`, it works perfectly by returning all the students but this defeats the main purpose of pagination. I'm either not sure where the problem is, either in the publish function or the helper function. What I want to achieve is that the records in SchoolStudents colleciton should be paginated to display 2 records on a page.

This is the autorun

```
Session.setDefault('skip', 0);
Template.view.onCreated(function () {
    Session.setPersistent('ReceivedSlug', FlowRouter.getParam('myslug'));
    this.autorun(function () {
        Meteor.subscribe('SchoolStudents', Session.get('skip'));
    });
});
```

this is the helper method

```
students(){
        let myslug = trimInput(Session.get('ReceivedSlug'));
        if (myslug) {
            let mySchoolDoc = SchoolDb.findOne({slug: myslug});
            if (mySchoolDoc) {
                let arrayModuleSchool = StudentSchool.find({schoolId: mySchoolDoc._id});
                if (arrayModuleSchool) {
                    var arrayStudentIds = [];
                    arrayModuleSchool.forEach(function(studentSchool){
                       arrayStudentIds.push(studentSchool.studentId);
                    });
                    let subReadiness = SchoolStudents.find({_id: {$in: arrayStudentIds}}).fetch();
                    if (subReadiness) {
                       return subReadiness;
                    } 
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

This is the publish method

```
Meteor.publish('SchoolStudents', function (skipCount) {
  check(skipCount, Number);
    user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:this.userId})
    if(user) {
        if(user.emails[0].verified) {
           return SchoolStudents.find({userId: this.userId}, {limit: 2, skip: skipCount});
        } else {
           throw new Meteor.Error('Not authorized');
           return false;
        }
     }
});
```

Blaze template

```
<section class="tab-section" id="content4">
    {{#each student in students}} 
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: -20px;">
    <!-- Begin Listing: 609 W GRAVERS LN-->
      <div class="brdr bgc-fff pad-10 box-shad btm-mrg-20 property-listing card-1">
          <div class="media">
              <div class="media-body fnt-smaller">
                  <a href="#" target="_parent"></a>
                  <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="/student/{{student.slug}}" target="_parent">{{student.firstname}}  {{student.lastname}}</a></h4>
                  <p class="hidden-xs" style="margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: -10px;">{{trimString student.useremail 0 110}}</p><span class="fnt-smaller fnt-lighter fnt-arial">{{course.createdAt}}</span>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div><!-- End Listing-->
  </div>
  {{/each}}
    <ul class="pager">
        <li class="studentprevious"><a href="">Previous</a> </li>
        <li class="studentnext"><a href="">Next</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
```

the pagination event

```
'click .studentprevious': function () {
        if (Session.get('skip') > 0 ) {
            Session.set('skip', Session.get('skip') - 2 );
        }
    },

    'click .studentnext': function () {
        Session.set('skip', Session.get('skip') + 2 );
    }
```

Comment: I got the same issue that you faced and then I have checked the kurourin GitHub repositories and there is another subscribes based pagination.click this link - https://github.com/Kurounin/PaginationExample

Above link will help you